# Command execution sequence in batch file

Tags: windows-10

Ho I can create a batch file that should execute command only after successful execution of previous command?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to super user. You would need to use what is called an IF statement, which allows you to run checks on your code before execution. In order to help further please expand your question. Information such as what you are trying to achieving with this batch file would be greately useful for us to provide a robust answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by successful. If want to check if `foo.exe` didn't return any [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) other than 0, use:

```
@echo off
start /wait foo.exe
if errorlevel 0 (
  start /wait bar.exe
)
```

to run `bar.exe` after `foo.exe` returned exit code `0`. You can ommit `start /wait` if application you are testing is console one, and not desktop one.

More information on that: [How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/334879/3109484), in answers by [Samuel Renkert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/334890/3109484) and [Garry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11476681/3109484).

Comment: I don't think you need the nesting here; `if errorlevel 0 start /wait bar.exe` should be enough. However, this is heavily dependent on what definition of "successful execution" the OP has in mind.

Answer (score 0):

besides the errorlevel solution posted by Hex and improved by Michael's comment.

This one is even quicker for what you want to do.

firstcommand && secondcommand

The second command will only run if the first command was successful. i.e. if the first command didn't return an error.

In the example below,  dir asfsds  returns that output but also returns an error

If you do dir asdfsss & blah   then it will run blah  regardless of whether the first command (dir sdsdf) returned an error or not.

But if you run them with &&  in between them, then if the first is an error, it won't run the second.  It's based on the idea of boolean algebra If A is true and B is true then A AND B is true.   So to find out if A and B are true, you could check A and B, or you could be "lazy" or efficient rather, and just check one and if it's false you know the whole expression is false. And if it's true then you have to check the one other.  So A && B  checks A and only checks B if it has to check B, so only checks B if B is true. But that boolean algebra concept is applied to commands, so it runs the first one, the first one might return an error or it might not, and if the first does return an error then it won't try running and checkin the second one,  and if the first one doesn't return an error then it will try to the second one.  No doubt the expression itself would return true(no error) if both are true and false(error) otherwise.

> C:\Users\user>dir asdfsdf
>   Volume in drive C has no label.  Volume
>   Serial Number is B411-D580
>
> Directory of C:\Users\user
>
> File Not Found
>      <---------------- See the output of dir asdfdsds  above
>
> C:\Users\user>dir asdfsdf & echo a
>   Volume in drive C has no label. 
>   Volume Serial Number is B411-D580
>
> Directory of C:\Users\user
>
> File Not Found a  <--- see the 'echo a' ran
>
> C:\Users\user>dir asdfsdf && echo a
>   Volume in drive C has no label.
>   Volume Serial Number is B411-D580
>
> Directory of C:\Users\user
>
> File Not Found
>
> C:\Users\user>

If you did dir filethatexists && echo a   then you will see the first command runs successfully and then echo a runs.  Similarly echo a && echo b